# Adjusting line-height for different ems in stacked text?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to "stack" some text, but have one small word inserted among the big words, like so:

```
THIS
 
IS AN

important

SENTENCE
```

I have the HTML laid out with the main text in its own class, with the font size at 8em, and a span in the middle for the smaller word. In the CSS, I've set up a class for "important":

```css
.important {
    font-size: 0.5em;
    line-height: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
THIS<br>IS AN<br><span class="important">important</span><br>SENTENCE<br>
```

...and it's there, and looks great, BUT the line-height doesn't seem to take. The word "important" is 0.5em in size, but the line-height is just as tall as the rest of the words, resulting in a giant space after IS AN and before "important".

I've tried with the `<br>` both inside and outside the span, on both sides of "important", like

```
THIS<br>IS AN<span class="important"><br>important<br></span>SENTENCE<br>
```

...but I just can't seem to get the line-height to take. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a side-effect of the markup used. Replace the line breaks (`<br>`) with block-level containers to achieve the desired behavior (stack the words on one another), e.g.:

#### HTML

```html
<div>THIS</div>
<div>IS AN</div>
<div class="important">important</div>
<div>SENTENCE</div>​
```

You can also lose the `line-height` declaration, as it no longer serves a purpose:

#### CSS

```css
body {
    font-size: 8em;
}
.important {
    font-size: 0.5em;
}​
```

#### References

- [A live demo on dabblet](http://dabblet.com/gist/3071761)
- [HTML block level elements on Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Block-level_elements)

---

***Note:** You may use any block level elements, e.g. `div` containers or `p` elements. Paragraphs will be more appropriate semantically, but you should be aware of any default styles applied to them such as thick padding, bottom margins etc..*

Answer (score 1):

Line height is a tricky thing to control with precision, because of the vagaries in the way different browsers and OS interpret the how the calculation is made. [Adam Twardoch](http://www.myfonts.com/person/Adam_Twardoch/) wrote about how [line height varies with browsers](http://webfonts.info/webfonts-know-how/part-2-problem-line-height) over at webfonts.info, where there's also a more general piece on [working with line-height](http://webfonts.info/webfonts-know-how/part-1-we-need-talk-about-line-height).

Line-height controls aren't really intended for more 'graphic' layouts, but are a part of the designers toolbox for setting legible paragraphs. As Eliran said, use block elements for what you're trying to do. That way you can control positioning far more accurately.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the most kosher way to do it, but I've had success giving negative margins to text like that instead of adjusting line height.

Answer (score 0):

I usually prefer `<p>` for adjusting line height. Try something like this:

CSS:

```
p.important
{
    font-size: 0.5em;
    line-height: 0.5em;
}
```

HTML:

```
THIS<br>IS AN<br><p class="important">important</p><br>SENTENCE<br>
```